# How to integrate Graph Engine with C# application

Tags: graphengine

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) 
The type initializer for 'Trinity.Global' threw an exception.

Comment: i want use Global.LocalStorage.##_Accessor_Selector() method to work graph engine in memory data processing integration with .Net App.   I have changed Target Plateform to x64 . but that not help me . need help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this to change setting 
Tool-Option --   Project and solution-- Web Projects--checked checkbox use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web site and project
    enter code here

And 
able to Trininty Dll integrate with my WebAPI (Odata) application